# mongoDB join in MERN Stack Project

Tags: node.js, express, join, mern

i have two collection and i want to join them. (please guide me in Mongo 3.6 syntax). Products:

```
 {
        "_id": "5b55c3b303d3a94e0c11e634",
        "createdAt": "2018-07-23T12:01:55.760Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-07-23T12:01:55.760Z",
        "address": "1111 West Chicago Avenue, Chicago, IL 60642",
        "lang": "en",
        "poster": "/images/products/poster/pizzzzza.jpg",
        "new_price": 45,
        "off": 10,
        "old_price": 50,
        "summary": "10% Cash Back at Pie-Eyed Pizzeria",
        "title": "Pie-Eyed Pizzeria",
        "status": true,
        "category_id": "5b449e6b6f94bb4ab0b67b70"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5b55c34a03d3a94e0c11e631",
        "createdAt": "2018-07-23T12:00:10.409Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-07-23T12:00:10.409Z",
        "address": "505 N. Lake Shore Dr. Suite #204, Chicago, IL 60611",
        "lang": "en",
        "poster": "/images/products/poster/asdasd.jpg",
        "new_price": 34,
        "off": 66,
        "old_price": 100,
        "summary": "No-Chip Mani-Pedi at MC Lash Studio (Up to 66% Off). Three Options Available.",
        "title": "MC Lash Studio",
        "status": true,
        "category_id": "5b449cf96f94bb4ab0b67b6b"
    }
```

My second collection is ProductDetails:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5b55c3b703d3a94e0c11e635"),
"createdAt" : ISODate("2018-07-23T16:31:59.323+04:30"),
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-07-23T16:31:59.323+04:30"),
"location" : "",
"detail" : "Enter your Detail",
"terms_of_use" : "Enter terms of use",
"description" : "Enter your description",
"product_id" : "5b55c3b303d3a94e0c11e634"
```

},

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5b55c35003d3a94e0c11e632"),
"createdAt" : ISODate("2018-07-23T16:30:16.368+04:30"),
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-07-23T16:30:16.368+04:30"),
"location" : "",
"detail" : "Enter your Detail",
"terms_of_use" : "Enter terms of use",
"description" : "Enter your description",
"product_id" : "5b55c34a03d3a94e0c11e631"
```

}

and i want something like this in mongodb

```
select * from Products left join ProductDetails on Products._id = ProductDetails.product_id
```

i tried $lookup but i don't know how to put "Products._id" in $match.

```js
import Products from '../models/ProductsModel.js';
export function getProductDetail(req, res, next){
  Products.aggregate(
    {
      $lookup:
      {
        from: "productsdetails",
          pipeline: [{$match:{product_id:Products._id}}],
            as: "product_detail"
      }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define you pipeline stages and then pass them to the aggregate function, as follow:

```
import Products from '../models/ProductsModel.js';
export function getProductDetail(req, res, next){
        // Pipeline stages definition 
        const pipeline = [
            { $match: {
                    "_id" : "5b55c3b303d3a94e0c11e634" // From you request params
                }
            },
            {$lookup: {
                    from: "ProductDetails",
                    localField: "_id",
                    foreignField: "product_id",
                    as: "details"
                }
            }
        ];
        Products.aggregate(pipeline).exec()
            .then((products) => {
                // Handle your response
            })
            .catch(err => {
                next(err);
            });
}
```

Comment: not working, the error message is: Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators

Comment: I forgot the $match and $lockup operators, please check out this new query